# При нажатии на кнопку изменить текст

Tags: javascript, html

Как при нажатии на кнопку

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#view-report">
                            View response
                        </button>
```

поменять текст "view response" на "hide response", а при повторном нажатии вернуть "view response".

Comment: ругаться не обязательно. Ответ дан, но прошу, в следующий раз, с подобным вопросом, воспользуйтесь поисковиком - так вы получите ответ намного быстрее.

Comment: спасибо  дорогой но  надо ешо при второй клике  обратно возврашалось

Comment: Готово, кода чуть меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = function() {
  if(this.innerHTML == "Hide response")
  {
    this.innerHTML = "View response";
    return;
  }
  else this.innerHTML = "Hide response";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" id='btn'
                                data-target="#view-report">
                            View response
                        </button>
```

Comment: тебе одно + ответа

Answer (score 1):

```js
let show = true;
function changeText(ev) {
    if(show) {
        ev.innerText = "Hide response"
        show = false;
    }
    else {
        ev.innerText = "View response"
        show = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeText(this)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view-report">
    View response
</button>
```

Можно без доп. переменной, хранить инфу в самой кнопке.

```js
function changeText(ev) {
    if(ev.getAttribute('data-show') === "true") {
        ev.innerText = "Hide response"
        ev.setAttribute('data-show', "false"); 
    }
    else {
        ev.innerText = "View response"
        ev.setAttribute('data-show', "true"); 
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-show="true" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeText(this)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view-report">
    View response
</button>
```

Comment: работает дорогой но при второй клике остается ето hide

Comment: @Aram77778 вы про второй клик ни слова не говорили

Comment: а как при второй клике показал первое значение

Comment: @Aram77778 обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо все работает